# Angular 5: PDF and Excel Button on datatable does not show up

Tags: angular, pdf, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular-datatables

I am trying to add buttons to the datatable in Angular 5. The PDF and Excel button does not show up. Can someone help? 'dtOptions' and .angular-cli.json looks like this:

`dtOptions:
    "dom" : "Bfrtp",
    "buttons": ["colvis", "copy", "print","excel","pdf"]
    //.angular-cli.json looks like this
    "styles": [
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
            "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
            "styles/app.scss",
            "styles.scss",
            "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.css"
        ],
    "scripts":[
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js",
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js"
             ],`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

`

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js
```

`